# App ionic : Chrome not sending right cookies in cors http request

Tags: angular, google-chrome, http, cookies, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing an ionic application that uses http requests and authenticates with cookies.

First, I login :

```
login(login, password): Observable<number>{

    let body = new FormData();
    body.append("pseudo", login);
    body.append("password", password);

    let url = this.baseUrl+"/service/login";

    return Observable.create(observer => {

        this.http.post(url, body, this.options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                // code omitted

            },
            err => {
                // code omitted
            }
        );
    });
}
```

I receive the cookie in the set-cookie response headers :

```
access-control-allow-credentials:true
access-control-allow-origin:http://127.0.0.1:8100
access-control-expose-headers:WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization
cache-control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 14 Dec 2017 13:02:15 GMT
set-cookie:multipass-cookie=Fe26.2**99636c19e52bde1e7ed632373ddfc5ee505aa19377c39aa40b7982d97fbcb023*6QYsXbrTmi5LoYMxngrPzA*y5Z5oz9Tlq-Gzn9yj9yZ-ue5hDWxt1D7XV_nnohdyTA**e38b047dddebd4a83975d883917f375de87673c0542e8f774d5034a5337000b9*cRK9uIlDVDnYoJ0lwwRTy-7hBWEhWZQojw91XPHj3-U; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
vary:origin,accept-encoding
```

Then I do another call that needs the cookie :

```
getUserInfos(): Observable<number>{

    let url = this.baseUrl+"/service/playerInfo";

    return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.http.get(url, this.options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                // code omitted                 
            },
            err => {
                // code omitted
            }
        );
    });
}
```

And the cookie is not sent in the request headers. Chrome instead sends other cookies I didn't ask for (PHPSESSID and i18next) :

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,la;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=hmkgpm6hb10m9ldi7nm5vqnjq0; i18next=fr-FR
Host:www.jeuxpresto.com:2773
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8100
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8100/?ionicplatform=ios&ionicstatusbarpadding=true&http://127.0.0.1:8100/ionic-lab
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
```

I use the option withCredentials:true, it is set in this.options constructed as below :

```
this.headers = new Headers();
this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true });
```

Working well on Firefox, the right cookies are sent, and everything is ok.
What could be the problem ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record : it was a configuration problem with the server. 
The cookie configuration SameSite was on "Strict".
Everything worked ok when we changed it to "None".

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. @Linwe, Where did you changed the SameSite  configuration?

Comment: It's a header you set on the server. It depends on the tech your server uses. Maybe you can find more informations here : https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/04/14/preventing-csrf-with-samesite-cookie-attribute/

Comment: @InêsGomes I'm using php 7.4 laravel on the server,  can you pls share how did you fix it? it might be the same

Comment: @Linwe did you manage to fix it?